# SQL Server Merge Replication, Agent Batch Size

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

Is there anyway to increase the merge agent batch size **after** the publication is created?

I know `DownloadGenerationsPerBatch` flag when creating a new Publication, however what I'm looking for is a way to modify this flag in a running publication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefered method would be to alter the merge agent profile.

See this link for a detailed explaination on how to do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152515.aspx

The setting will take effect the next time the merge agent runs.